# error showing in the downloaded dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, google-api

Am on integrating google calander using google api version 3, using NuGet package `Install-Package Google.Apis.Calendar.v3` and also referring [this link](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse?repo=samples#hg/Calendar.VB.ConsoleApp). while running the web application am getting the error as :

> System.IO.FileLoadException**: Could not load file or assembly
>   '`System.Net.Http.Primitives`, **Version=2.2.22.0**, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (*Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040*) --->
>   **System.IO.FileLoadException**: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

the web config file am using for this is:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.9.0" newVersion="2.6.9.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.9.0" newVersion="2.6.9.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.22.0" newVersion="2.2.22.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.0.0" newVersion="2.2.22.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

the package config is like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <package id="Google.Apis" version="1.9.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Google.Apis.Auth" version="1.9.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Google.Apis.Calendar.v3" version="1.9.0.1110" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Google.Apis.Core" version="1.9.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.9" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.22" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Zlib.Portable" version="1.10.0" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

bith are similar to what in the [reference link](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse?repo=samples#hg/Calendar.VB.ConsoleApp)

**Updates:**

> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) 
>   at
>   Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.<AuthorizeAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
>   in
>   c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\test\default\Src\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs:line
>   59    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()    at
>   testVB.home.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   D:\GoogleCalandarDemo\testApp\testVB\home.aspx.vb:line 26

**does it means the error is in the `dll` i was referring?**

Comment: Ensure you're referencing correct assembly in project references. The version must match 2.2.22.0

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the "Microsoft Http Client Libraries" from Nuget? This might be the issue.

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have 2.2.22.0 version assembly in your reference. Try to clean and build your project again. (In this case check your bin as well that it has 2.2.22.0 version)

And replace

```
 <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.0.0" newVersion="2.2.22.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

with

```
 <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.22.0" newVersion="2.2.22.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```