# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am developing web application for uploading file on Google Drive. But whenever it execute connect method it always throw error.

i have tried everything like.
http://wordpress.kjetil-hartveit.com/2014/06/04/google-api-nightmare-how-i-fixed-the-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-primitives-version1-5-0-0-exception/

[error showing in the downloaded dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645734/error-showing-in-the-downloaded-dll)

[Powershell Cmdlet Missing Assembly Google Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542812/powershell-cmdlet-missing-assembly-google-api/18646197#18646197)

But still nothing is working.

```
<!-- Snippet from web.config -->
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.9.0" newVersion="2.6.9.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.22.0" newVersion="2.2.22.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.9.0" newVersion="2.6.9.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.22.0" newVersion="2.2.22.0" />
</dependentAssembly>

<!-- Your <runtime> tag should look something like this now -->

<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.9.0"`enter code here` newVersion="2.6.9.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.22.0" newVersion="2.2.22.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.9.0" newVersion="2.6.9.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.22.0" newVersion="2.2.22.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: This issue has been logged on the client library.  You may want to follow that thread https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/555

Comment: Error : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.