# Google API System.IO.FileLoadException

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, .net-assembly

I have this error while attempting to create a calendar it keeps saying this :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I have the Http.Primitves dll in my bin and also I have the reference in the web.config like this :

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.29.0" newVersion="2.2.29.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

It still is looking for version 1.5 Here is the code that tries to create a calendar in API:

```
 int iReturn;

    const string serviceAccountEmail = "Email.com";
    const string serviceAccountCertPath = @"C:\wwwroot\_CreateCalendarEvent.p12";
    const string serviceAccountCertPassword = "pass";
    const string userEmail = "email.com";
    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(serviceAccountCertPath, serviceAccountCertPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet |
                                 X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet |
                                 X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(

   new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
```

The Error indicates that it breaks at `ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(`
How do I Update the reference for this I used Nuget to update and install google API from this question [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645734/error-showing-in-the-downloaded-dll)

It still is giving me error same.